# How to get xml data using ajax in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to use ajax in jquery to get data for my page...

The problem is that the url which i call has some query strings to be sent along with it...

for example: the url which i call for getting data is:-

**http://mysite.in.dataengine.aspx?t=abcde&token=h34jk3&f=xml**

the data i get in response from this url can be in xml format or java script arrays(whichever i choose)

for eg...the xml wil look like this:-

```
<root version="1.0">  
    <Regions>
    <Region SubCode="MWEST" RCode="west"/>  
    <Region SubCode="MCENT" RCode="north"/>  
    <Region SubCode="THAN" RCode="south"/>  
    </Regions>  
</root>
```

and the javascript array would look like this :-

```
Region = new Array();
Region.push(new Array('MWEST', 'west'));
Region.push(new Array('MCENT', 'north' ));
Region.push(new Array('THAN', 'south'));
```

So when i get the data i want to store it in a drop down box.(using ajax)

**Note** I can get either xml OR javascript arrays as the returned data, not both together.

Comment: Please format your code via the Code button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys...but i have found the solution....Like i said...that i get in return either xml or javascript array...So..i'm using javascript arrays.. and using a function in jquery**($.getScript)** which fetches an external javascript code via ajax...Thus i am getting all my data now through ajax in jquery...

Answer (score 1):

You can make an ajax call along with parameters like this:

```
var paramsData = "t=abcde&token=h34jk3";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dataengine.aspx",
    data: paramsData,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
           //process xml from server
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks....this was very helpful...although it didnt work bcoz i was gettin the data from an external source to be ajaxed..but still..this will come in use for another part of my project...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to get the data in JSON format, as Json comes natively to javascript and it much easliy manipulated using javascript as compared to XML. The easiest way i can see to work on your problem is to store all your data whether xml or json & put it inside a hidden div and then use jQuery to populate that data in a drop down box.
Here is an amazing jquery plugin with example that should ease your work 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryclientdb

Answer (score 0):

Just parse it. I"m not sure if this will work, but it might:

```
xml = ...
region = new Array();

$(xml).find('Region').each(function() {
  region.push(new Array($(this).attr('SubCode'), $(this).attr('RCode'));
});
```