# refer javascript array from html file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a question regarding ajax array. I have create two arrays in a javascript file like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
categoryarray = [];
productarray = [];
```

Then if I want to refer to these arrays from another javascript file with the script inside html follows the script of the javascript file that creates two arrays, but it doesn't show anything, not even console reporting error.
Below is how I refered the array in another javascript file, it didn't work.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'my_script.js',
        success: function(data) {
            for(var k=0;k<categoryarray.length;k++){
                if(categoryarray[k][0]!==""){
                    $('.tree').append('<li id="Cate_' + k + '">'+categoryarray[k][1]+'</li>');
                    for(var l=0;l<productarray.length;l++){
                        if(categoryarray[k][0]==productarray[l][2]){
                            $('#Cate_' + k).append('<ul id="Pro_' + l + '"></ul>');
                            $('#Pro_' + l).append("<li>"+productarray[l][1]+"</li>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.tree').text('Failed to load the data');
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong and how to fix them? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please show what you have tried that isn't working. You mention ajax in title and it is *asynchronous* which may or may not be part of your problem. As it currently stands the information provided is far too vague

Comment: @charlietfl Hi! I tried directly referring to the content of the array. I have edited the post with that. As for the ajax, I used it to read two xml files and save the data separately inside two arrays, each array contains multiple elements each with several attributes.

Comment: When are you calling your script? Maybe it happens _before_ the document is ready and your arrays are not yet initialized. As a side note, whay are you waiting for the document to be ready to initialize the arrays, and aren't doing it, say, in a separate script somewhere in the beginning?

Comment: Ok but if your `for()` loop runs immediately then the ajax would not have populated the arrays yet. If the `for()` loop runs before the js that contains the arrays loads then they will be undefined. Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda Yes, you are right. Script in HTML will run as soon as browser parse page and jQuery will wait until page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I never bother considering the order stuffs!!

Comment: I tried put the for loops inside another javascript files goes after the old js files, but it shows nothing. Did I miss something?? I have edited the codes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all place your code inside a function that you will call on some event. If you want to process your arrays after AJAX call then call that function after AJAX success. Browser render HTML from top to bottom so your script in HTML will run as soon as browser bump into script. On the other hand jQuery on ready will wait until all of the page content is fully loaded (all images, assets etc) - whole DOM, so your arrays will stay undefined.
You can fix it either by moving that code from HTML to jQuery ready function or by moving array declarations in HTML. 
Anyway, if that script from HTML should run when document is ready, then it is more reasonable to move javascript code from HTML to jQuery ready function.

Comment: Thank you! That's really clarifies a lot! I have made some modification but it still doesn't work. Did I miss something like "$.ajax(" ??

Comment: AJAX is used to get data from remote server or file. If you didn't get any data your arrays will be empty. Yes, you need to make ajax call if you are getting data that is not hardcoded inside script.

Comment: HI Mirko! I have included ajax but somehow it still doesn't work. Can you help me figure out what I have missed or done wrong? Sorry for the troubles I am new to javascript.

Comment: No problem. Thing is that you need to get data from somewhere. From where you are getting data for categories and products ?

Comment: I stored xml files data in them in the first javascript. In this case, do I need php session or something to pass the value? This two js files should work on the same page, old ->  left, new -> right, they are dlivided using table.

Comment: Yes, it would be good to call php page from ajax that gets your xml data from server and then execute that javascript. Here is the way you can fetch xml data (just in this case you are not calling .aspx but .php page) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237559/how-to-get-xml-data-using-ajax-in-jquery

Comment: Thank you so much Mirko! You are really helpful!!